# ListView из Fragment в Android

Tags: android, material-design

уважаемые коллеги. Во время разработки возникло желание сделать элементы списка подобным образом, как это делает Гугл (прямоугольники с текстом).[image: как здесь] возникает вопрос, как реализовать? С Андроидом работаю недавно, в голову лезет только Listview состоящий из Fragment. Наведите путника на путь истинный, буду благодарен за подобные реализации.

Comment: гугловская биб-ка `CardView` - `compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'`

Comment: Лучше гуглите recycler view, он даже немного гибче, чем listview. Там как раз найдете, как использовать cardview. А вообще можно и listview, и для итемов задать нужный margin

Comment: @tim_taller спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

1.В Layout `Activity` размещаете

```
<ListView
 android:id="@+id/lvMain"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:dividerHeight="5dp"<!--ширина разделителя-->
 android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</ListView>
```

2. В активти создаете переменную

```
ListView lvMain = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMain);
```

3.Создаем `Adapter` в который будут передаваться нужные значения (вместо `names` ваш массив значений):

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names);
```

4. Создаете `Layout` `simple_list_item_1` и в нем реализуете как должно все отображаться в одной ячейке.
5. Присваиваете `Adapter` к `ListView`

`lvMain.setAdapter(adapter);`

Answer (score 0):

Привет, недавно велась разработка где необходимо было юзать карточки (CardView), да да ето карточки Google. Так вот после недолгого поиска нашел ето https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib

Сначала качаешь cardslib-core,
потом нужные тебе модули.
Создаешь карточку

```
ColorCard card = new ColorCard(this.getActivity());
card.setTitle("A simple colored card " + i);
```

Создаешь адаптер

```
mCardArrayAdapter = new CardArrayAdapter(getActivity(), cards);
```

Бросаешь карточку в адаптер

```
ArrayList<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>();
cards.add(card);
mCardArrayAdapter = new CardArrayAdapter(getActivity(), cards);
```

Прикручиваю адаптер к CardListView и додаю немного анимаций

```
mListView = (CardListView)       getActivity().findViewById(R.id.carddemo_extra_list_viewanimations);
AnimationAdapter animCardArrayAdapter = new   AlphaInAnimationAdapter(mCardArrayAdapter);
animCardArrayAdapter.setAbsListView(mListView);
if (mListView != null) {
      mListView.setExternalAdapter(animCardArrayAdapter,mCardArrayAdapter);
    }
```